# object as a parameter in C# event and registered in Labview

Tags: c#, events, labview

I have a custom event in a usercontrol in C# which takes object as one of its parameter. With this parameter, I will send whatever datatype(typecasted to object).This event will be registered in labview and the object parameter will be typecasted into respective datatype

```
public delegate void UpdateDatatagEventHandler(string datatag,string datatype,object value);              

public event UpdateDatatagEventHandler UpdateDatatag;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.UpdateDatatag != null)
    {
        object value = this.textBox1.Text as object;
        this.UpdateDatatag("Goodness", "GOODness", value);
    }
}
```

If the event is raised like this, it's not captured in Labview. But when I rise the event like below, it's captured in Labview. But my intention is to typecast the `textbox1.text` into object and get in Labview.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.UpdateDatatag != null)
    {
        object value = this.textBox1.Text as object;
        this.UpdateDatatag("Goodness", "GOODness", this);
    }
}
```

If Iuse object array instead of object as the parameter in the delegate

```
   public delegate void UpdateDatatagEventHandler(string datatag,string datatype,object[] value)
```

I am able to the Event in the labview. What should be done for this?

Comment: What does "it's not captured in Labview" mean?

Comment: And why are you using `as object`? There's an implicit conversion from anything to `object`...

Comment: @Enigmativity .It means that Event handler in labview is not invoked when that event is raised in the .NET side.

Comment: @JonSkeet .I tried implicit conversion also.

Comment: @Guna1992: Right, and it will have exactly the same effect. There's no benefit in using `as object` here.

Comment: @JonSkeet: If Iuse object array instead of object as the parameter in the delegate "public delegate void UpdateDatatagEventHandler(string datatag,string datatype,object[] value)". I am getting Event in the labview.

Comment: I'm not sure why that comment was addressed to me, as it has nothing to do with what I was talking about. It sounds like you need to edit it into the question as more information. Without having used Labview, I don't think I'll be able to answer the question...

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see your LabVIEW code. But if you can get to the .NET object reference perhaps you can use an Invoke node on it to run the .ToString() method and consume it's output in LabVIEW.